# Get Date Time Hours and Minutes with leading Zero

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out the simplest code to add leading zeros on to the hours and minutes from the DateTime.Now function. I need to combine only the hours and minutes, and I don't need the rest of the date.

Whats the best way to do this?

My code looks like this:

```
DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
```

However I get data such as 16:4 for 4:04PM and I need it to look like 16:04. I'm familiar with the msdn articles on datetime formatting but I didn't see anything that addresses this specifically.

Is it possible combining `DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();

If not how would I pull only the HH:MM out of DateTime.Now easily?

Looking for least lines of code possible because this is something that I will be utilizing often.
Thanks

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm") // for non military time
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") // for military time (24 hour clock)
```

Using `hh` vs `h` will do a leading 0. Same with `mm` for minutes. If you want seconds, you can use `ss`.

```
MM - Month with leading 0
M - Month without leading 0
dd - Day with leading 0
d - Day without leading 0
yyyy - 4 Digit year
yy - 2 Digit year
HH - Military Hour with leading 0
H - Military Hour without leading 0
hh - Hour with leading 0
h - Hour without leading 0
mm - Minute with leading 0
m - Minute without leading 0
ss - Second with leading 0
s - Second without leading 0
tt - AM / PM
```

There are many more. You should check the MSDN documentation for the full reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Answer (score 9):

If you only want the hours and minutes as separated values you can use

```
DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("00.##") + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("00.##");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should check out MSDN's [Standard Date And Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Using interpolation you can do this:  `Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm}")` where *Console.WriteLine* could be a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the formatting parameter in `ToString`

```
[DateTime]::Now.ToString("hh:mm")
```