# Convert Minute to Two Digit

Tags: c#, datetime

Please have a look on the code below:

```
DateTime timerTest = timerView;
txbTimer.Text = timerTest.Day + "/" + timerTest.Month + "/" + timerTest.Year + " " + timerTest.Hour + ":" +  timerTest.Minute;
```

I am suppose to get Date and Time in the `txbTimer` Which I am getting. If the date is 14/8/2015 14:10

But when the time (minute) is 01 - 09 the `txbTimer` will become 14/8/2015 14:1 in this case I wanted the expected output like 14:01 and not 14:1

Please help me

### **Edit**

My Code is

I think the lines which adds hours and days might be changing so here is the updated code.

```
DateTime timerView = DateTime.Now;
DateTime timerTest = timerView;

if(robHour.Checked == true)
    timerTest = timerView.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0));
else if(robDay.Checked == true)
    timerTest = timerView.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));

txbTimer.Text = timerTest.ToString(); //timerTest.Day + "/" + timerTest.Month + "/" + timerTest.Year + " " + timerTest.Hour + ":" + timerTest.Minute.ToString();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTime string format in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303110/datetime-string-format-in-c-sharp)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341886/get-date-time-hours-and-minutes-with-leading-zero

Comment: What does `.ToString("mm")` mean? Are you sure it's a valid formatting? Did you follow the link I provided?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Thanks for the link your solution worked for me. mm part is commented as someone suggested me. Surely gonna upvote and mark as answer

Comment: They suggest to use `timerTest.ToString("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm")`. here `timerTest` is a `DateTime` not an `int` like the `Minute`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this

```
timerTest.Minute.ToString("D2");
```

For more formatting follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here are examples provided by MSDN

> ```
> 1234.ToString("D")     -> 1234
> (-1234).ToString("D6") -> -001234
> ```

Comment: Nope still the answer is same... one digit minute

Comment: It should work, I tried it and the documentation have samples

Comment: You selected this answer but do **not** use number formatting when you can (and should) use datetime formatting. Just saying..

Comment: I do agree with @SonerGönül

Answer (score 6):

```
DateTime timerTest = timerView;
var result = timerTest.ToString("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm");
/*
dd -> two digit day
M -> one digit month
yyyy -> four digit year
hh -> two digit hour
mm -> two digit minute
*/
```

> HH:(00-23) will look like 00, 01..23.
>   hh:(01-12 in AM/PM) will look like 01, 02..12.

Comment: I dont know but still using this one also getting the same one digit Minute

Comment: This is wrong and kind of missing. `hh` is for 12-hour format. And provide an `IFormatProvider` that has `/` as a date separator and `:` as a time separator.

Answer (score 4):

[`Minute` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of a `DateTime` returns integer. That means it *can't* have any leading zeros.

You can use [`mm` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#mmSpecifier) to get it's string representation with leading zeros for single digit minutes.

By the way, your method is not a good way to get string representation of a DateTime. Using `ToString()` method with a culture that have `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) and `:` as a [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (eg: [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ) is better.

```
txbTimer.Text = timerTest.ToString("dd/M/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lJzzBJ)</kbd>.

Comment: I dont know but for some reason it is still showing one digit minute

Comment: @MohitShrivastava That's not possible. Have you _ever_ tried my code? I added as a demo which shows truly `14/8/2015 14:01` for example

Comment: Your demo is working but for some reason this not working in my project

Comment: Could you please have a look on the edited part of the Question

Comment: @MohitShrivastava What is your `CurrentCulture`? Using only `ToString()` _might_ use `m` specifier based on your culture.

Answer (score 2):

This will solve the issue you are facing

```
DateTime timerView = DateTime.Now;
DateTime timerTest = timerView;

if(robHour.Checked == true)
    timerTest = timerView.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0));
else if(robDay.Checked == true)
    timerTest = timerView.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));

txbTimer.Text = timerTest.Day + 
               "/" + timerTest.Month + "/" + 
               timerTest.Year + " " + timerTest.Hour + 
               ":" +  timerTest.Minute.ToString("D2");
```

Comment: Hossein Narimani Rad has already answered this. What is the use of answering same thing

Comment: I am new on SO and thus I thought I'll give you an exact answer with full code. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [DateTime Format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
txbTimer.Text = timerTest.ToString("d/M/yyyy HH:mm");
```

Working example [here](http://goo.gl/mWdXuQ).

Also take a look at one of the [pre-defined standard formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: In response to your edit of the question: you might want to provide more details like what is the datatype of txbTimer? What is the value of CurrentInfo.CurrentCulture? Is it possible to add Console.Writeline before setting the value in txbTimer?

Answer (score 0):

To get the minute component of a DateTime as a number from 00 through 59, use the "mm" custom format specifier.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 18, 9, 1);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("mm"));

// Displays "01"
```

Documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-mm-custom-format-specifier